# How can I change width of a line without changing its stroke width in inkscape?

Tags: width, line, inkscape

I am new to inkscape and I would like to know if there is anyway to increase/change the width of a line without changing its stroke width.

I want the line to have a fill color and a narrow black stroke (preferably 2px).

Thanks

Comment: The width of a line *is* the stroke width. Please make your question more clear. Are you trying to convert a stroke to a path? There's a menu item for that.

Answer (score 6):

You can convert a thick-stroked curve using the `Stroke to path` command (in the `Path` menu): this won't change its aspect, but instead of being defined as a line with a given width, this will give a polygonal shape (a sort of ribbon). Then you can give this ribbon a stroke colour and thickness (`Shift`-click on the chosen colour).

Comment: Thank you very much Joce. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Masood: pleasure. If indeed that's the answer you were looking for, the usage is to accept it by clicking the "check" symbol on the left.

Answer (score 5):

In the Inkscape version 1.0 there are four buttons on the right side of the toolbar. The first one is responsible for enabling of scaling the stroke while changing the width of an object. Click it to disable this kind of scaling.
[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This is currently the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's a small trick to change the width line as Inkscape doesn't provide a mechanism.

1. Close the current file in Inkscape
2. Edit your file in a normal ASCII Editor
3. Find your object (e.g. a spline), it will be a path ... statement
4. Change the "stroke-width" manually e.g. as
   `<path style="fill:none;stroke:#80ffff;stroke-width:0.164583px; ....`

**Tip:** If you have a large file, you can assign your object a unique color (here 80FFFF) and you can then search that color code "80FFFF" in your ASCII Editor.

Comment: This was helpful. However using unique color value of only "80FFFF", in Inkscape's RGBA field in the Fill or Stroke paint dialog, cause the color to disappear, and that is because of the missing "A" part of that value (the Alpha or "opacity"). Changing that to "80FFFFFF" causes it to show up properly.